# Redis-cli with password

Tags: redis

I am using redis and trying to open CLI of redis using this:

```
$redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mysupersecretpassword
```

and getting and error :

> (error) NOAUTH Authentication required

why so ?

Comment: Are you using the correct password? What is your Redis and redis-cli versions? And I am I correct in assuming that the error is provided only after you actually try to type a command at the cli's prompt?

Comment: if  I use $redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379  then if authenticate  its working. And my redis version is 3.0.3

Comment: Is it possible that your super secret password is parsed by the shell, i.e. contains magic characters?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a '$' in your password then it won't work. So set the password without the "$".

Comment: Just put the password in quote... don't need to remove the $

Answer (score 103):

My solution is put the password in single quotes like:

```
$redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a 'thisizmy!PASS'
```

Answer (score 18):

If you have '$' in your password, make sure to enclose the password with single quotes. Then it will work.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this would usefull to someone. If you have already open the redis-cli console window, you can type the authentication like this:

```
auth 'your-password'
```

and then the console would response with OK

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Redis Access Control List - ACL (Redis 6 and above), you log in with `--user` and `--pass`:

`redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 --user redis_user --pass 'redis_password'`

or if you are already in `redis-cli` console you can authenticate with:

`auth redis_user 'redis_password'`